# Xamarin build error Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: exception, build, xamarin, filenotfoundexception

always i try to Build my Xamarin app i get this error. And i dont know why.
I use the System.Security.dll of .Net Framework 4 and i though this should work.
Thanks.

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2):
>   Error: Exception while loading assemblies:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly
>   'System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono
>   for Android profile?
>
> Dateiname: 'System.Security.dll'
>
> bei
>   Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
>
> bei
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly)
>
> bei
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly)
>
> bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute()
>   (TaskManager2)

Comment: I'm receiving this error myself, did you ever manage to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue with System.Web. All I had to do was to add the System.Web reference from the GAC.

**update**

GAC is probably the wrong word here. Those are the default .net (mono) framework libraries. You can find them in Project/References/ and right click to 'Edit References' you'd find the framework libraries under Packages tab.

Comment: What is the GAC? It would be useful to clarify this to make this answer more useful.

Comment: GAC is probably the wrong word here. Those  are the default .net (mono) framework libraries. You can find them in Project/References/ and right click to 'Edit References' you'd find the framework libraries under Packages tab.

Comment: I'm receiving this error myself, can't seem to fix it, any other ideas/tips?

Comment: More information about GAC would be very helpful. After adding the Xamarin dlls for System.Web I still have the problem. The problem emerged after I added the AWS resources to my working Xamarin project.

Comment: I found this worked for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557097/xamarin-build-error-exception-while-loading-assemblies-system-io-filenotfoundex

Answer (score 8):

Add the missing `.dll` to your project(s).

`Right click on the References folder -> Add Reference -> Browse -> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\<version number>\ -> <missing.dll>`

`Clean` your project and `rebuild`

Comment: Hey! The solution worked but gave another error stating: `The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly...`. can you please help me with this?