# "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v13'" After replacing with support library v4

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-play-services, android-support-library

I'm working with a **Xamarin.Android** project in **Visual Studio** that have the following components **Azure Mobile Services** version 1.1.0, **Google Play Services (ICS)** version 13.0 and **Android Support Library v13** version 19.1.0.

When I try to update the components to the latest versions **Azure Mobile Services** version 1.2.2, **Google Play Services (ICS)** version 18.0 and **Android Support Library v13** version 20.0. I get error about duplicate versions conflicting between Android Support libraries v4 and v13 cause Google Play Services version 18.0 now uncludes Android Support Library v4.

Now what I'm trying to do to solve this is removing Android Support Library v13 cause v4 is already included.

When I try to build the project i get following error in the output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(863,2): error : Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v13, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(863,2): error : File name: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v13.dll'
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(863,2): error :    at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(863,2): error :    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(863,2): error :    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute()
```

I can't find any mention of the Xamarin.Android.Support.v13.dll anywhere in the files in the project.

What I am aiming for is that the app **must have Azure Mobile Services and Google Play Services** at the latest version and **support devices with API 15 or higher**.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding it? It looks like one of these project source files problems that occur from time to time.

Comment: Yes, every time I try to build, I clean it first

Comment: The same question answered here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557097/xamarin-build-error-exception-while-loading-assemblies-system-io-filenotfoundex

Answer (score 0):

I have personally had success using the nuget package of the android support lib, instead of the component from the component store (i think its no longer being maintained?)