# Could not load assembly 'System.Web in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, reference, system.web

I've just load a additional project to my Xamarin.Android project. After add reference i get this error? What is the problem?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Exception while loading assemblies:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Web,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name:
>   'System.Web.dll'    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() KinectBudka.Droid

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Did you load a windows project to your xamarin android project?

Comment: I have this too.  It just suddenly appeared and I'm unsure what action caused it to creep-in.

Comment: This worked for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557097/xamarin-build-error-exception-while-loading-assemblies-system-io-filenotfoundex